# How to parse a C/C++ header file by doxygen(Now to invoke doxygen's API?)

Tags: doxygen

I commented my source file with doxygen syntax, example:

```
/**
 * @brief get Root tree
 */
void get() {}
```

Now I want to get the function's brief message by doxygen's API, who can help me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way to get access to this kind of information is to [generate XML file using Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_generate_xml) and then use your favorite XML parsing library to access it.

Answer (score 0):

The XML output is the preferred way to extract information gathered by doxygen.

You can use your favorite XML parser or download doxygen source package and look in addon/doxmlparser for a C++ API to interface with doxygen's XML output. This parser is optimized to deal with the potentially large amount of XML output produced by doxygen in an efficient way.

As an alternative you can also directly interface with doxygen's internals. For an example look at addon/doxyapp in the source package. Note this is a more volatile interface and that with this approach you are bound to the terms of the GPL v2.